# Install Eclipse JDT on top of CDT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt, eclipse-jdt

I have the eclipse CDT installed, and I would like to install Java development functionality (JDT) on top of my CDT installation. I've been Googling from an hour but I can't figure out how to do this.

What plugin do I need to install? What update site do I need to use?

Answer (score 101, accepted):

All versions of Eclipse have a standard base, then a specific set of plugins, depending on the version.  All you have to do is go to the *Help > Install New Software* menu, select the Eclipse update site (e.g. "Galileo - http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo"), and under the *Programming Languages* section, select *Eclipse Java Development Tools*.

If you don't see the Java Development Tools in the list, click on the "already installed" link on the install page--you may already have the Java tools installed.

Comment: It gives me an error:

Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo. http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo is not a valid repository location.

I did try a different update site (http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/galileo) and tried to install the "EPP Java Package", but it gave me all sorts of dependency errors about Mylyn, WST, EMF and other things.

Any further suggestions?

Comment: Just checking, are you using Eclipse 3.5 Galileo or a previous version of Eclipse?

Comment: I am using Eclipse 3.5 Galileo. I ended up getting it to work by installing all the dependencies manually (Googling for their update sites and installing the packages found on their update sites).

I'm still wondering whether there was a better way to do this.

Comment: Just to clarify: when I say I got it to work, I mean I got the "EPP Java Package" to install successfully. The Galileo update site (http://download.eclipse.org/releases/galileo) still doesn't work for me.

Comment: It would be nice if they added the JDT acronym to the name, as nothing showed up until I used the full search string recommended above.  Thanks for setting me straight!

Answer (score 0):

Remember to write `http://` before the download.eclipse..... if you don't put that it won't work

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse 2020-06 the weakest precondition seems to be

1.) JDK 11

2.) eclipse.ini has top entries

```
-vm
<jdk-11/jre-11 path>/bin
```

3.) JDT appears in "Install New Software" repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-06 as "Eclipse Java Development Tools"

NOTE: Installation of Java 11 is not required, downloading/extracting ZIP File is sufficient, e.g. if you prefer to continue development with Java 8

Answer (score 0):

**Update** for Eclipse Release 2021-3

Here, with the JDT-Release JDK 11 or later is already installed

- Choose Menu Help->Install New Software,
- Select Work With: "2021-03 - [http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03"](http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2021-03%22)
- Filter "Development Tools"
- Select "C/C++ Development Tools SDK"
- Complete Installation with Next ... Restart Eclipse