# How do I enable Java support with Aptana? There's no Java support or any plugins. Add Software has no URLs

Tags: java, aptana

I want to work with Java in Aptana but there is no support for it, plus there are no URLs to add software with (it's empty). What do I do?

Comment: @Steve J - I use it for JavaScript and Python.

Answer (score 5):

This is how I configure Aptana to get java support:

1. Verify the version of Eclipse that it is using. Go to menu Help → About Apatana... -> Click on the Eclipse icon, the version to take into account is the one for feature 'Eclipse plataform'.
2. Make sure the update site for your version of Eclipse exists in the Available software sites.

   - First find the update site that corresponds to your version of Eclipse; for instance, if you have Eclipse plataform version 3.7 (also known as Indigo) the update site would be http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo/ (make sure you have the correct URL).
   - Then go to menu Window → Preferences, then choose Install/Update → Available Software sites. There you should have an entry for Eclipse and the location should be the update site from the previous step; if it doesn't exist just add it with the appropriate information.
3. Install 'Eclipse Java development tools'. Go to menu Help → 'Install new software...'. Select your Eclipse update site, from the drop down list. A list of available updates/features will be shown. Look for Java (using the filter field) or navigate to 'Programming languages'; in either case, check the box for 'Eclipse Java development tools', click next and follow any additional steps until installation is done.
4. Configure preferences for Java in Aptana. Go to menu Window → Preferences, in the left pane you should now see an item called 'Java'. The subitem 'Installed JREs', should have at least one entry (this is the version of JRE that will be used during development. It is possible to add more JREs there (Not going into the detail here, as it is not really the question to be answered).

Now you should be able to add Java projects and so on.

Answer (score 4):

Aptana is designed for web development, so supports many web development features such as HTML, JavaScript, css syntax highlight and support for popular current web development languages and frameworks such as Rails.

If you want to do Java development I recomment you download [Eclipse for Java Developers](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-developers/indigosr1)

You can then install aptana as a plugin following these instructions http://update1.aptana.org/studio/3.2/024747/index.html to have the best of both worlds.

Answer (score 2):

This SO question on how to add the Java Development Tools (JDT) for a CDT Eclipse distribution also answers this question:

[Install Eclipse JDT on top of CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853450/install-eclipse-jdt-on-top-of-cdt)