# How Do I Add Java To My Eclipse for C/C++

Tags: java, c++, c, eclipse, ide

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install eclipse JDT on top of CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853450/install-eclipse-jdt-on-top-of-cdt)

I am looking for instructions for my mac and pc. I recently installed eclipse for c and c++ developers and don't want to install another copy for java.

Comment: what eclipse version did you install? You should be able to build java projects from afaik any of them.

Comment: Eclipse for C/C++ developers

Comment: If you go to File > New Project is Java listed?

Comment: I fixed it I just had to go to new -> other. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Post your answer down below and accept it when you can. This will let future visitors know of the solution.