# How do I include JAVA development tools in already installed Eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Install eclipse JDT on top of CDT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853450/install-eclipse-jdt-on-top-of-cdt)

I already Installed:

```
 Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
 Version: Indigo Release
 Build id: 20110615-0604
```

Now I want JAVA development tools in Eclipse. How do i Install that ?

Please post graphic guides.

Answer (score 1):

just to go eclipse marketplace and search after Java tools and install

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Help menu and press Install New Software

[image]

alternatively, use the [Marketplace](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/).

[image]

Comment: Cannot complete the install because of a conflicting dependency.
Software being installed: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)

Comment: @ Aviad: Im getting this error.

Comment: post the entire stacktrace, especially the `Software currently installed:`

Comment: Software currently installed: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (epp.package.cpp 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
  Only one of the following can be installed at once: 
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.1.v201109091335 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.1.v201109091335)
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v201106131736 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.0.v201106131736)
    Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v201202080800 (org.eclipse.platform 3.7.2.v201202080800)

Comment: Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (epp.package.cpp 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
    To: org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.feature.feature.group [1.4.0.20110615-0550]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: EPP CPP Feature 1.4.0.20110615-0550 (org.eclipse.epp.package.cpp.feature.feature.group 1.4.0.20110615-0550)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f]

Comment: Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Java Development Tools 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1 (org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120120-1414-7z8gFcuFMP7BW5XTz0jLTnz0l9B1)
    To: org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.0.v20110530-9gF7UHNFFt4cwE-pkZDJ7oz-mj4OSEIlu9SEv0f)

Comment: To: org.eclipse.platform [3.7.0.v201106131736]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Eclipse Platform 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q (org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 3.7.2.v20120207-1839-9gF7UHPDFxGjd-PqDr2jX_4yKaumkoHTz04_q-q)
    To: org.eclipse.platform [3.7.2.v201202080800]

Comment: What happens when you go to the "already installed" link on the install page--you may already have the Java tools installed. (Do you see Java Developement Tools in the list?)

Comment: Yes. I can see Java Development Tools there. I think I dont have JDT installed.

Comment: On the "About Eclipse" listing there is nothing related to JAVA.

Comment: I have double checked the Installation Details. I dont have JDT. Can I run Two seperate Veriosn of Eclipse Side by Side ? I can donwload Eclipse JAVA EE and run that without affecting my current Eclipse Installation ?

Comment: Have you tried to restart eclipse and actually use one of the java tools that seem to be missing?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21578/discussion-between-curious-apprentice-and-aviad)